# REACT - Dynamic SVG should be clipped to it's parent container size but not sure how to go about it

Tags: reactjs, svg

Essentially I have 12 different svgs in a folder. I have I have an SVG imported as a react component and then used as component. This SVG needs to be scaled according to its parent div. So far I have done the first bit but I don't know how to clip this SVG to its parent or size to scale to it's parent size.

APP.JS

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { ReactComponent as StrataSVG } from './StrataSVG/Strata_16.svg'; // summoning 
SVG from local folder

import './App.css';

const Container = styled.div`
   height: 50vh;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: ${props => props.bg};
`;

const Pattern = styled.svg`
   height: 1000px;
   width: 1500px;
`;

function App() {
   const [colorChosen, setColorChosen] = useState("green");
   const [bgChosen, setbgChosen] = useState("yellow");
   
  return (
      <Container bg={bgChosen}>
            <Pattern fill={colorChosen}>
               <Path></Path>
            </Pattern>
      </Container>
  );
}
const Path = () => <StrataSVG/>; // this is the imported PATH on line 3


export default App;
```

[image: Image of how it currently looks]

Comment: Since it's a pattern, a easy solution would be using it as css background and leting it repeat so that it creates a pattern. You will need an svg element containing only the path you now have inside the pattern.

Comment: Could I change path colour of svg when its a css background??

Comment: No, but if you are using a data:uri and since you are using react maybe you can target the part of data:uri string where you are defining either the fill or the stroke color.

Comment: perfect that ended up working. Now the only task is to dynamically change the data url sp i can interchange svgs but not sure how to go about that